# WordPress Post Thumbnail Resizing Issues

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, thumbnails

I have recently developed a website in WordPress, I have a few thumbnail sizes defined by `add_image_size();`

For example if you look here: http://bit.ly/kSTU0Q

Images in the right hand channel at the very bottom under 'MORE PRODUCT NEWS' we have this defined for

```
the_post_thumbnail()

add_image_size( 'side-excerpt', 86, 93);
```

So would be:

> the_post_thumbnail( 'side-excerpt',
>   array('class' => 'alignleft') );

If you look WordPress does not seem to adhere to my sizing specifications and I have used the '**Regenerate Thumbnails**' plugin and this seems to make near as no difference.

Hopefully you guys can shed some light on the situation.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You might find some information about the function at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your issue is with your crop style.

add_image_size has a third property that is crop style and defaults to false (soft proportional cropping.

"Box resizing shrinks an image proportionally (that is, without distorting it), until it fits inside the “box” you’ve specified with your width and height parameters."

The reason that your regenerate thumbnails is not working correctly, is because you are using this soft mode, and it seems like the result you are actually looking for is hard crop.

"in this mode, the image is cropped to match the target aspect ratio, and is then shrunk to fit in the specified dimensions exactly."

so you will want to change

```
add_image_size( 'side-excerpt', 86, 93);
```

to

```
add_image_size( 'side-excerpt', 86, 93, true);
```

For more information see:

http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size